# Can I make a contract that can pull out liquidity from Uniswap pair?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, uniswap

Guys asked me to pull out LP from a renounced contract that has 1% max transaction (this condition applies to ***any wallet***). Now I should make 78 x 2 transaction to pull all. I want to find the way to lower fees. Decided to make a contract for that "operation impossible".

**Contract should make several easy steps:**

1. Pulling fixed token amount from liquidity
2. Send pulled tokens to any wallet from the list (we add this list)
3. Repeat till draining all
4. Send WETH or ETH to my own wallet

I'm sure this method will lower fees. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

Have you check out Uniswap's [Multicall](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/periphery/base/Multicall) method? It looks like what you are describing here.